# How do I return the length of the path found by Breadth First Search?

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to augment the typical BFS algorithm to also return the length of the path it found. Here's what I've written so far:

```py
from collections import deque
length = 1
visited = set()
q = deque()
visited.add("Start")
while q:
    v = q.popleft()
    length += 1
    if v == "End":
        return length
    else:
        for neighbor in graph[v]:
            if neighbor not in visited:
                visited.add(neighbor)
                q.append(neighbor)

return 0
```

Here, I'm assuming a graph of strings. An example graph could be

```
graph = { "Start" : ["A"],
          "A" : ["B"],
          "B" : ["End"],
          "End" : []
          }
```

I understand that this is wrong as it will count the entire size of graph and not just the length of the path to the goal. How can I modify it to return the length of the path to the goal it found?

Comment: Try associating the "distance to this node form the start" information with each node. There are a lot of ways to do this. For example, keep tuples of (node, distance) in your queues; or build a separate dict with that information (mapping nodes to their distances). Either way, it should be straightforward to keep that information updated as the algorithm progresses.

Comment: I just want to comment on the code you uploaded, how can you return when that is not a `def`? and the loop cant start with an empty deque. Please correct it so that others can debug your code idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the advice of @Karl Knechtel, I was able to write it!

```py
from collections import deque
visited = set()
q = deque([("Start", 0)])
visited.add("Start")
while q:
    v, length = q.popleft()
    if v == "End":
        return length + 1
    else:
        for neighbor in graph[v]:
            if neighbor not in visited:
                visited.add(neighbor)
                q.append((neighbor, length + 1))

return 0
```